# OCaml: Including module but making type abstract

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I want to extend the `Array` module,

```
module type VEC =
sig
  include module type of Array
  type 'a t
  (* other stuff *)
end
```

with concrete implementation

```
module Vec : VEC = struct
include Array
type 'a t = 'a array
(* other stuff *)
end
```

Using `include Array` gives me the advantage of being able to continue using functions from the `Array` module and also having access to operators. However, if I call `Vec.make 4 0` it will return an `int array`.

What I want it to do is to be able to continue using the functions from the `Array` module but  have them return `int Vec.t` instead. I am wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's possible. You can still copy/paste the files you want and modify the types by hand.

Comment: I figured that was probably the case, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no easy way except redeclaring functions of `Array` using `'a t` in the definition of `VEC`:

```
module type VEC = sig
  type 'a t

  (* Instead of  include module type of Array, hand write all the types of
     the function in Array, replacing 'a array to 'a t *)
  val length : 'a t -> int
  val get : 'a t -> int -> 'a
  ...
end

module Vec : VEC = struct
  type 'a t = 'a array
  include Array
end
```

Comment: I figured it probably wouldn't be possible, essentially I want to keep the `a.()` operator for my `VEC` module. Unfortunate that one can't overload the `.` operator in OCaml